# docker odoo 9 install pika error

Tags: docker, odoo-9, python-pika

I have a simple docker build that I want to achieve. Pull the base image odoo:9 and install pika library

FROM odoo:9

RUN pip install pika

but can't proceed as I'm getting this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boBzT.png)
btw, I am using docker in windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is that, I just pull the Dockerfile from the official Docker Odoo. Add the line "&& pip install pika" as shown in the attached image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9nmL.png)

build again and you have a customize docker image with pika library installed.